# new and delete in a c++ library being called from a C program

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

I have a series of c++ classes stored in a library with a C interface (see example below). And I have a C program that includes this c++ libary via the C interface. This seems to work well until I tried to create a class in the libary with `new` and `delete`.

I am using gcc to compile the C code and g++ for the C++ libary, I crated the projects with Eclipse on unbunu.

The error message that I get is

```
undefined reference to 'operator new(unsigned int)' 
undefined reference to 'operator delete(void*)'
```

Libary H file

```
#ifndef CFOO_H_
#define CFOO_H_
#ifdef __cplusplus

class CBar {
   public:
      int i ; 
};

class CFoo {
   public:
      int work();
};
extern CFoo g_foo ;
extern "C" {
#endif /* __cplusplus */    
   int foo_bar( ) ;    
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif /* __cplusplus */
#endif /* CFOO_H_ */
```

Libary cpp file

```
#include "CFoo.h"
CFoo g_foo ;

int CFoo::work() {
   CBar * b = new CBar(); 
   delete b; 
   return 1; 
}

int foo_bar( ) {
   return g_foo.work( );
}
```

Main c file

```
void * __gxx_personality_v0 ;
int main(void) {
printf( "foo_bar 10   =%d\n", foo_bar() ) ;
     return 0; 
}
```

I have tried a few things with out success, any thoughts?

## Edit

It looks like it was a problem with the auto generated make files produced by Eclipse. Once I manualy changed the C applcations makefile to link with g++ instead of gcc I was able to build the applcation. See comments below for more information.

Comment: This is a link problem, not a code problem. Can you give us info about how you link your code?

Comment: It's not linking in the C++ runtime. You should use "g++" as the link command, rather than "gcc".

Comment: If any C++ code is in the program, the translation unit containing `main` should be compiled as C++ code, not as C code.

Comment: @unapersson You are correct, when I changed the make file to link with g++ insted of gcc it built correctly. I'm used eclipse to make the makefile in the first place and didn't even think about it. thanks

Comment: +1 for a [Short, Self-Contained, Compilable Example](http://sscce.org) program.

Comment: @aschelper - can you expand on your `main` comment, or provide a link? Thanks!

Comment: Supposedly the C++ library is static, right? A dynamic library should not have such an issue I believe.

Comment: @Rob: IIRC, if the `main()` is compiled as a C source, then the constructors of global objects won't be called before entering the `main()` (and the destructors won't be called after main's exit). There must be some other similar glitches (like the initialization of the C++ runtime). Thus, no matter what, if you want to use C++ libraries, then linking with the C++ runtime and having a C++ `main()` function is mandatory.

Comment: As a side note: Am I wrong, or this question is answered through comments??? . . . :-D . . .

Comment: Don't you mean to compile the C code with gcc? And that is the reason why you use `extern "C"` to let g++ make the C++ library C compatible. When you use g++ to link, the C code is compiled as C++ code. Is that what you really want? Sorry that this is not an answer. I can't comment yet.

Comment: @paercebal - yes, it was answered via comment. I have copied @unapersson's comment to an answer so OP may close.

Comment: @rob thanks I was searching for a way to close a questions answered by the comments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quoting unapersson: It's not linking in the C++ runtime. You should use "g++" as the link command, rather than "gcc".

Comment: How would I link with g++ but still compile with gcc or clang?